# How to insert text within the element through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Can someone give me a hint to locate an element in selenium?

Where is what I tried to select

```
WebElement  hello =  driver.findElement(By.className("input-box"));
```

Error from Eclipse:

```
Can't find symbol 'GetGraphicsResetStatus'.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: .input\-box
```

Thank you again.

original html

```html
<div data-v-7d31c51a="" data-v-126e1ccf="" class="input-box"><textarea data-v-7d31c51a="" placeholder="inputhere~" maxlength="500" autofocus="autofocus" class="textarea" style="height: 60px;"></textarea><div data-v-7d31c51a="" class="indicator" style="bottom: -30px; right: 100px;"><span data-v-7d31c51a="" class="">0</span>/<span data-v-7d31c51a="">500</span></div></div>
```

Error from trying 
WebElement  hello =  driver.findElement(By.className("textarea"));

Can't find symbol 'GetGraphicsResetStatus'.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: .textarea
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:26.402Z'

Adding my jar file and my codes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzyfu.png)

Comment: Have you tried wait until element preset? And in order to set the value, you have to get the textarea element, rather div element.

Answer (score 1):

Try the xpath:

```
 WebElement hello =  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@placeholder='inputhere~']"));
```

Comment: Can you check that is there any iframe present above the element ?

Comment: one match if search iframe  in inspector  but if search <iframe>, no

Comment: after googling, don't think it has iframe.

Answer (score 1):

The element is a dynamic element, so to send a *character sequence* to the desired element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.input-box>textarea.textarea[placeholder^='inputhere']"))).sendKeys("JohnMax");
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='input-box']/textarea[@class='textarea' and starts-with(@placeholder, 'inputhere')]"))).sendKeys("JohnMax");
  ```

Comment: @JohnMax Can you inspect the HTML and traverse upwards and look out if the element is within an `<iframe>` tag and update the question accordingly?

Comment: one match if search iframe  in inspector  but if search <iframe>, no

Comment: @JohnMax Please update the question with the text based HTML of the element including the iframe tag.

Comment: after googling, don't think it has iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You have consider wrong class name for the `inputbox`.Your class should be.

```
WebElement  hello =  driver.findElement(By.className("textarea"));
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you post? Also check if there any iframe which stopping to identify element locator?

Comment: updated post with iframe information. thank you again

Comment: @JohnMax, I asked you check iframe in your html.What you have provided that is CSS not html.can copy the entire html and shared as link.Thanks

Comment: ok, let me see how to do that, this is the only iframe  stuff.

Comment: after googling, don't think it has iframe.

Comment: The error which you have mentioned that is not related to element locator error.Some of your selenium package missing here.have you added all selenium jars and import all pakages.When I ran given your code it is working fine.can you show your entire code.

Comment: just upload a pic  of  my jars file. Thank you.